# OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1) even with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, storage

I have an application that generates some PDFs and CSV files and at the moment I am saving these files into the `files` folder in the application directory of the Android phone. Then the user needs to manually move the files to another folder (for example Documents or Downloads).

I would like to save the file to the Documents or Download folder (one of the two, is the same) automatically at runtime, after the files are generated by the app. The target devices has Android 11 so I have any kind of problems with managing the external storage.

Android Manifest:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.example">
    <!-- PERMISSIONS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
...
...
```

Permissions requested at startup:

```dart
  requestPermissions() async {
    try {
      await [
        Permission.storage,
        Permission.manageExternalStorage,
      ].request();
    } catch (e) {
      LoggerService().error("PERMISSIONS REQUEST ERROR", e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Method that saves the files:

```dart
  Future<String> export(Uint8List pdf, {String? fileName}) async {
    Directory dir = Directory(EnvironmentService.documentsPath);
    String path = "${dir.path}/${fileName ?? "${uuid.v4()}.pdf"}";
    File file = File(path);
    await file.writeAsBytes(pdf);
    return path;
  }
```

Path where I am trying to save the files:

```dart
static const String documentsPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Documents";
```

When saving the file I always get `OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)` error, even if I have granted the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. The application will not be published on the Play Store, and needs to be working only on Android.

Any idea of what's happening?

Comment: You do not need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to create  sub folders and files in public Documents or Download directory in an Android 11 device.

Comment: So why do I get the error?